# Can I ask an imported module to modify main.py's globals?

Tags: python, module, global-variables

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
#module.py
def modifyglobals():
    global a
    a = 12

#main.py
from module import modifyglobals
modifyglobals()
print a  # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

since I think it modifies `module.py`'s globals, but not `main.py`'s.

On the other hand, I was expecting that this would work:

```
#module.py
def modifyglobals(g):
    g()['a'] = 12

#main.py
from module import modifyglobals
modifyglobals(g=globals)  # pass a reference to **main's globals** to modifyglobals
print a
```

But still it gives `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Question: **Why doesn't `main.py` pass a reference to *its own globals*, such that the called function can modify `main.py`'s globals?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why doesn't `main.py` pass a reference to *its own globals*, such that the called function can modify `main.py`'s globals?**

Because `g=globals` passes the `globals` *function*, not any particular global variable dict. When `globals` is called, it returns the global variable dict of whatever code called `globals`. You still end up calling `globals` in `module.py` rather than in `main.py`, so you get `module.py`'s globals.

Pass the actual global variable dict:

```
#module.py
def modifyglobals(g):
    g['a'] = 12

#main.py
from module import modifyglobals
modifyglobals(g=globals())
print a
```

Of course, most of the time, having a function modify its caller's global variables directly is a bad idea. Don't actually do this.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, in 99,999% of my Python code, I never do this, I know it's not a good idea. It's just that in a particular tricky case, it would simplify much things. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to access module's globals, you could do something like this:

```
# module.py
def modifyglobals():
    global a
    a = 12

# main.py
import module

module.modifyglobals()
print(module.a)
```

In case you want to modify your main.py's global, you could do something like this instead:

```
# module.py
def modifyglobals(mod):
    mod['a'] = 12

# main.py
import module

a = None

module.modifyglobals(globals())
print(a)
```

That said, I really discourage you to use neither these 2 ways at all. Personally I rarely consider the usage of module globals at all. If I decide to define module globals is either because I'll use them to be private at the module level, or as a singletons, modules's constants or maybe module's cache. There are much better ways to do data transfer between modules and the above ones shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes and no, because then I would have to prefix every variable with `module.`. In long computations such as `X + Y * Z + ...`, I would like to avoid the long writing of `module.X + module.Y * module.Z + ...`.

Comment: @Basj Edited my answer

Comment: @Basj: In a computation like that, you probably shouldn't be using either module's globals. You should be using local variables and function return values.